# writing to file object, python

Tags: python

I have the following code

```
for i in np.arange(10):
   f = open("file_"+str(i)+".dat",'w')
   for j in np.arange(100):
      f.write(str(func(i,j)))
      f.write("\n")
      print func(i,j)
   f.close()
```

Now, I can see the output on the terminal because of the `print` command but the files that it is creating are empty. It isn't able to write the output to the file. How can I do it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with scope. Can you show the code of `func()`?

Comment: have you tried to print str(func(i,j)) ?

Comment: `func()` is a long code, it just returns a double value, I think it is alright because I get the value on the terminal

Comment: @twall where should I use `print` ? I am getting the values on the terminal

Comment: You're missing an end parentheses in the line `f.write(str(func(i,j))
`- be sure to copy and paste your code correctly

Comment: Would a `f.flush()` before the `f.close()` be enough for you?

Comment: `f.flush()` doesn't make a difference, the problem is it fails even for the first time

Comment: But are you sure that `func` is actually returning a value, rather than printing it?

Comment: Take `func` out and substitute something simple, e.g. `float(j)` and see if you can still reproduce the problem with such a simple script.

Comment: OK, it was silly from me, actually `func` was taking some time to complete amd I didn't know that you could not view the contents before the file closed down.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try:

```
for i in np.arange(10):
   with open("file_%i.dat" % i,'w') as f:
       for j in np.arange(100):
           val = func(i,j)
           f.write("%s\n" % val)
           print val
       f.flush()
```

Comment: The `.flush()` is not neccessary. It is done automatically when the output file is closed. The `with` causes closing the file.

Comment: I'm quite aware the `with..` closes the file. We're forcing a `flush` to check whether it improves the problem or not.

Comment: Yes. This was my main reason for the comment. When any file in any OS is closed, it is always flushed. This way, trying one more explicit `flush` is not going to help. The `flush` should basically be used when writing to `stdout` or the like (or redirected) file. The only reason in the case is to get the latest information from the write buffer to a display.

Comment: ident 4 spaces more the f.flush(), and you will be able to read results in the file before the end of processing.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. It both displays the value and writes it to the files:

```
import numpy as np

def func(i, j):
    return i + j/1000.0

for i in np.arange(10):
    f = open("file_"+str(i)+".dat",'w')
    for j in np.arange(100):
        f.write(str(func(i,j)))
        f.write("\n")
        print func(i,j)
    f.close()
```

My guess is that Daniel Roseman is right, and that the problem is hidden in your `func`.